# How to layout 4 views side by side with 1 view centered

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to layout 4 views (2 buttons, 2 TextViews) at the top of my activity. I need button_2 to be centered horizontally, TextView_2 to take up the rest of the space to the right-hand side of the view, button_1 to wrap_content and be pinned to the left of the parent and textView_1 to fill the space between button_1 and button_2.
[image: mock diagram to show what I mean]

My code so far:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="button_1"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_2"
    android:text="textView_1"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="button_2"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="textView_2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_2"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button_2" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you. I obviously went down the wrong path trying to use linear layout!

Comment: one comment, the relative layout height needs changing to wrap_content or it covers the whole screen.

Answer (score 1):

`Relative Layout` will suit to your condition perfectly. Use `android:layout_toRightOf`, `android:layout_toLeftOf`, `android:layout_alignParentRight` and `android:layout_alignParentLeft` properties wisely.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_1"
            android:layout_toleftOf="@+id/button_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hello there"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView_1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_2"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, I believe this has the same result as anmol's answer. I went down the wrong path trying to use linear layout!

Comment: Yes it is, Relative layouts are much better when you need more complex alignments. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

remove layout weight in child linear layout and height is change to wrap content for textview and button to fulfull your requirements

Comment: Relative layout like the other 2 answers suggested seems to be the right approach to the problem. thanks for your time.

Comment: with my pleasure